Trigger Power BI Dataflow using Power Automate as soon as Databricks Workflow finishes
I would like to set up an automation such that whenever my Databricks workflow is completed, it should trigger Power BI Dataflow. One of the option is to use Power Automate. Is it possible to achieve it using Power Automate and how? Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thank you.
